# UITableView reloadData fires only once

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a TabBarController with two tabs SCHEDULE and DATE RANGE

When the view loads I'm hitting a webservice to collect the end users Schedule for that day. After parsing the XML I call ScheduleTable reloadData and all is well. I have tons of NSLog statements to follow the performance.

Clicking the DATE RANGE tab displays a DatePicker. After selecting the date range I have a button which when clicked passes the dates to the webservice again. In my log I can see the new dataset and can verify I have the data I need, when the code reaches the reloadData line, it does not fire the UITableView reload methods.

Any help is appreciated. I've tried viewWillAppear and self.ScheduleTable reloadData, neither have helped.

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's a little hard to help if the expected behavior is not happening but you swear you wrote the code correctly.

Comment: Put a dummy button and reload data when it is pressed. See if that reloads...if not, see if you have set the `datasource` of your `UITableView` to `self`

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you've connected the UITableView to the `ScheduleTable` IBOutlet in Interface Builder.

You say that the first refresh is working. That may be because it is automatically done by the tableview.

I understand that the second time you are calling reloadData programatically. If you haven't connected the IBOutlet, then your `ScheduleTable` variable is nil and `[ScheduleTable reloadData]` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> when the code reaches the reloadData line, it does not fire the UITableView reload methods. Any help is appreciated. I've tried viewWillAppear and self.ScheduleTable reloadData

Just before saying `[self.scheduleTable reloadData]` (never start an ordinary variable name with a capital letter), log the table:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.scheduleTable);
```

I'm betting it won't be the table and that you're accidentally sending this message into empty air.